# get multiple values from dc.js filters

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have 5 charts related in one dashboard, and I used dc.js it's working find,
what I want is: get dynamic overall data as a value by each click, like I have pie chart, I have bar chart, I have row chart and a J SON map,
pie chart is total projects (executed, on process, canceled)
bar-chart show the number of projects executed in month
map show the city of the project

what I want total executed , on process, canceled project in other place like in a div box each time the use click somewhere like bar-chart to show June project, or city that want to what projects done in DC.
I want it to be updated in filters, how can I do that, and I also want to get count of project group by type like (how much project in web design category, web development, software development) ?

please let know if you need more information.
I already have the data statically using PHP, but I need it to be update with dc.js filters.

Comment: It sounds like you could use a few number display widgets to display these values, but I doubt that's the answer you're looking for. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want overall values (after filter). I want to print them, in a span box.

Comment: You can use the [number display widget](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#number-display-widget) with [dimension.groupAll](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_groupAll). Hope this is what you're looking for!